# Does Data::Printer handle array slices?

Tags: perl

Apparently not:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my @values = 1 .. 99;
p @values[0..9];
```

Returns

```
10
```

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) doesn't shed any light on the matter as far as I can tell.

#### Questions

- Why doesn't the code above work?
- Is it possible to make it work without resorting to a temp?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The prototype on `Data::Printer::p` is `\[@$%&];%`, so it will accept a named array but not an arbitrary list or anonymous array reference.

There is a `Data::Printer::p_without_prototypes` function that will accept this input, and if you import `Data::Printer` with

```
use Data::Printer use_prototypes => 0;
```

then `p` in the current package will refer to this function, and accept your input.

```
use Data::Printer use_prototypes => 0;
my @values = 1 .. 99;
p [@values[0..9]];
```

Answer (score 12):

Data::Printer's `p` expects a single variable, but an array slice isn't a variable.

### Option 1 (Poor)

Call `p` for each element of the slice.

```
use Data::Printer;
my @values = 100 .. 199;
p $_ for @values[0..9];
```

Output:

```
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
```

I say this is poor because it doesn't show the offsets, and more importantly, it can result in no output at all if the list of indexes is empty.

### Option 2 (Better)

Build an array.

```
use Data::Printer;
my @values = 100 .. 199;
p @{ [ @values[0..9] ] };
```

This produces clearer output than the first option:

```
[
    [0] 100,
    [1] 101,
    [2] 102,
    [3] 103,
    [4] 104,
    [5] 105,
    [6] 106,
    [7] 107,
    [8] 108,
    [9] 109
]
```

If you find that too complicated, you could override `p`'s prototype and pass a reference to the array instead.

```
use Data::Printer;
my @values = 1 .. 99;
&p( [ @values[0..9] ] );
```

If you're ok with always passing a scalar or a reference (rather than variables) to `p`, you can use the following:

```
use Data::Printer use_prototypes => 0;
my @values = 1 .. 99;
p [ @values[0..9] ];
```

Comment: `@{[ ... ]}` to the rescue yet again :) What threw me off was the fact that even `p [ ... ]` wasn't working

Comment: So you can do `p @a` instead of `p \@a`, D::P only accepts variables, not expressions such as `[ ... ]`.